# How to use Objective-C @property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make an Navigation-based application.

What I want to do is to create some properties, in my .h file. ex:

```
NSString *Banana;
NSString *Apple;
```

then

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Banana;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Apple;
```

In the `.m file`, I want to call these properties, maybe in my `viewdidload`, and then give them some string inside, so when I run my application, it will show the string.

Comment: BTW, property names should start with a lowercase letter (`banana`, `apple`).

Comment: Don't forget to `@synthesize` your properties too.

Comment: better u read some tutorials or books.You will get good idea of view, NSString ,TableView and its delegates all kind of things

Comment: how do i call in the cellForRoq AtindexPath ? and thanks for the answer

Comment: The same way as in any other method in the class.

Comment: what about if i have NSMutableArray, and i want to store banana and apple inside the array ?

Comment: `[array addObject:banana];` Seriously, you should read some books/tutorials on Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

set like this,

```
self.Banana=@"ur string"
```

or

```
[self setBanana:@"ur string"]
```

Comment: how do i call in the cellForRoq AtindexPath ? and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `@implementation` do

```
@synthesize Banana;
@synthesize Apple;
```

In your `viewDidLoad` method, do

```
self.Banana = @"Yellow thing";
self.Apple =  @"Green or red thing";
```

Comment: what about if i have NSMutableArray, and i want to store banana and apple inside the array ?